# A couple of multitouch gestures are not working in 13.04 compared to 12.04

Tags: touchpad, 13.04, multi-touch

The three finger pinch and zoom as well as the three fingers to move the window are not working  in 13.04. Any ideas on how to fix this. My computer is the i5 Acer Aspire S7.

Comment: The three finger gestures - as described above - are also not working on my Apple Magic Trackpad. The two and four finger gestures are all working fine.

Comment: Seems to be a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1172172).
So I think you can close this question!