# Why were multi touch trackpad gestures removed from 13.04?

Tags: 13.04, multi-touch, design

I have an ASUS Zenbook UX31a and multi touch gestures worked great on 12.10, but after I upgraded to 13.04 every gesture stopped working, except for 2, 3 and 4 finger taps (the 3 finger tapped changed function, though).

According to [this comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1172172/comments/16) on Launchpad the gestures were removed by design, but no other explanation is provided.

What is the reason for removing trackpad gestures?

Comment: I just added the "design" tag since it's a question about design. Interesting question, and answers will also apply to this question; http://askubuntu.com/questions/285487/a-couple-of-multitouch-gestures-are-not-working-in-13-04-compared-to-12-04?rq=1, though I think this question is more useful.

Comment: Probably for the same reason emblems where dropped from Nautilus, configurability options are dropped every release, etc... :-(

Comment: I don't know the reason they were removed, but you can install [touchegg](https://code.google.com/p/touchegg/) which provides the same functionality :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes the touchpad gesture was removed but the nearest possible touch gesture software you can get is : [Easystroke Gesture](http://blog.ubuntulinuxguide.com/2013/03/add-gesture-recognition-to-ubuntu-1204.html)

Its available in Ubuntu Software Center.

or else you can try installing Touchegg

[Source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142182/mac-like-multitouch-support)

**Pre-requisites**
You need the latest vesion of Utouch to be running this. So add the following PPA

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:utouch-team/daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install utouch
```

**Installation**

Editing the config file
Config file is located here
~/.config/touchegg/touchegg.conf

Editing the file:
Open config file.

```
gedit ~/.config/touchegg/touchegg.conf
```

In the example below, the four finger drag gesture is configured to switch to Show Desktop

Four Fingers Drag

```
[FOUR_FINGERS_DRAG_DOWN]
action=SHOW_DESKTOP
settings=
```

Three Fingers Drag

```
[THREE_FINGERS_DRAG_UP]
action=MAXIMIZE_RESTORE_WINDOW
settings=

[THREE_FINGERS_DRAG_DOWN]
action=MINIMIZE_WINDOW
settings=
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this helps but it might help to restore the gestures in 13

Install touchegg using software center or synaptic or terminal

```
sudo apt-get install touchegg
```

Try [Mac like MultiTouch support](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142182/mac-like-multitouch-support)

Note that touchegg only works with touchpads that use the evdev driver and will not work with Alps touchpads.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, the drivers for your hardware may be automatically disabled by your system, or somehow unrecognized.

You can try installing **Synaptiks** in the Ubuntu Software Centre. It's a very good program. 
(One of my favourites)